# Get a unique max id for each instance using mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I am using a field with a prefix + auto increment id. For each instance i am taking the max+1 of ID and adding that to prefix. Can anyone suggest me a way to get this as unique please?

Comment: so whats the problem select max(id) from table; then add 1

Comment: max id will be same if multiple users use this feature at same time right?

Comment: but in mysql if while creating the table if you make id as primary key and select it auto increment you don't have to take care of inserting it every time it automatically has becomes unique

Comment: Yes you are correct, but in my case i want that id before inserting for the user to refer later his record, thats why i am attaching the unique id with a prefix and display it to user, hope you got it?

Comment: @Lenin Show us your table schema, sample data and expected output. Do you have a time (like a column log) in your table?

Comment: Is your id field primary key? if it is and if then you are trying to insert into the table, even if there are more than 1 user with same id it will generate an error primary key has to be unique

Comment: Also if you are trying it with multiple users I suggest to use `Hibernate`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Insert into table1 (id, user_id)
SELECT MAX(id)+1, CONCAT('a',CAST(MAX(id)+1 AS char))
FROM table1;
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca8c1/1)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using max(id)+1 is that there may be multiple threads making the same call, and so the result would not be unique.  There are several ways to solve this problem. The first is to use a sequence, where the database server will increment the number every time a new id is requested. You can use a table, with a number in it, but you have to lock the table when you update the number. Or you can allow the database to create the key for you when the table is inserted and retrieve the key after the insert. All are valid.

I prefer to use Hibernate and make it determine how to implement the ID for the database I am currently using.